# JQuery making the counter increase everytime onChange

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text box in jsp. I have to statify the below rules for text box:
1. When text box is entered invalid value twice, on the third attempt I will have to make a static text in text box and make it non-editable.

I have the below code, but the condition is not satisfied:

```
jQuery("#rfcDetail").change(function () {
                    var string, text;
                    var counter=0;                              
                    var regex = new RegExp("[A-Za-zÑ&]{4}[0-9]{2}[0|1]{1}[0-9]{1}[0|3]{1}[0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}$");
                    var regexTenCharacter = new RegExp("[A-Za-zÑ&]{4}[0-9]{2}[0|1]{1}[0-9]{1}[0|3]{1}[0-9]{1}$");
                    string = jQuery(this).val();
                    if( (regex.test(string)) || (regexTenCharacter.test(string)) ){
                        text = "";
                        document.getElementById("errorMsg").style.display = "none";
                        jQuery('input#btnNext').attr("disabled", false);
                        validrfc = true;
                    }else if(counter > 2){
                        jQuery(this).val('XAXX010101000');
                        jQuery(this).attr("disabled", true);
                        text = "";
                        validrfc = true;
                    }else{
                        counter++;
                        text="Enter valid value";
                        document.getElementById("errorText").innerHTML = text;
                        document.getElementById("errorMsg").style.display = "inline-block";
                        jQuery('input#btnNext').attr("disabled", true);
                        validrfc = false;
                    }
                    alert('Counter::'+counter);
                });
```

Here the counter variable is always 1 when I enter invalid value in textbox because I am doing it onChange everytime.

Is there any alternate approach for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second line of your function, you state that `var counter=0;` every time.
So any time you change something, it's going to start the counter at zero.  You need to remove that, then you need to make the counter a global variable (outside of your function) that holds the incremental number.

```
var counter = 0;
jQuery("#rfcDetail").change(function () { ...});
```